# Objective-C: Obscuring Data when in Background not working

Tags: objective-c

I've been trying to obscure data when the application enters the background state by hiding it in the task switcher.

here is my **AppDelegate.h** file

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder
<
    UIApplicationDelegate,
    MemberServicesManagerDelegate
>
{
    UIWindow* window;
    Reachability* reachbility;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *mainViewController;
@end
```

This is my **AppDelegate.m** file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
    { window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

        window.rootViewController = StartupController.instance.startingViewController;
        if(DEVICE == IPAD){
            self.mainViewController = window.rootViewController.childViewControllers[0];
        }
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //1
    //self.window.hidden = YES;

    //2
    //UIViewController *image = [UIViewController new];
    //image.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //[window makeKeyAndVisible];
    //[window.rootViewController presentViewController:image animated:NO completion:NULL];

    //3
        UIView *colourView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:window.frame];
        colourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        colourView.tag = 1234;
        colourView.alpha = 0;
        [window addSubview:colourView];
        [window bringSubviewToFront:colourView];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            colourView.alpha = 1;
        }];


    NSLog(@"BACK");       
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //1
    //self.window.hidden = NO;

    //2
    //[window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];

    //3
        UIView *colourView = [window viewWithTag:1234];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            colourView.alpha = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [colourView removeFromSuperview];
        }];

    NSLog(@"ForeGround");
}
```

I tried these 3 implementations but It won't hide the view when I enter the multitask switcher.

I tried this with both simulator and real device but it still won't work. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it in [applicationWillResignActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive?language=objc)

applicationDidEnterBackground is apparently too late and the system has already made a screenshot for the task switcher.

[More about application lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate?language=objc)